# Error in function syntax

Tags: r

Team,

I am trying to run following syntax but I am getting stuck. I get an error. Can someone please help.

> divider <- function(x,y) {
>   + result <- x/y
>   + print (result)
>   + }

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Is this a guess game? What error are you getting? How `x` and `y` defined?

Comment: I get following error:                                                          Error: unexpected '}' in "divider<-function(x,y){+result<-x/y+print(result)+}"

Comment: You need to remove the plus-signs "+" from your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit the `+` signs and it will work:

```
divider <- function(x,y) {  
  result <- x/y
  print(result)
}
```